# How to assign order to other admin user by admin/programmactically?

Tags: magento2, admin, assign

I want to assign an order to another admin user, for order fulfilment purpose.
I tried finding admin options, i didn't get any in magento admin.
Is it possible to do it in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Orders can not be assigned to admin users.

You would have to implement that yourself in a module or find one that let's you do this.

Comment: thank you, for the comments.
can you suggest, whether it would be better way to implement using sales_order extension atrributes